# Specflow tests in teamcity

Tags: specflow

How can I configure the build process in TeamCity to execute SpecFlow tests? 
I am using visual studio 2017 with the Specrun.Specflow nuget package installed. 
Can it be done with Nunit or SpecRun.exe?

Answer (score 1):

To run the SpecFlow tests with the SpecFlow+Runner (aka SpecRun), you need to do this:

1. Open your project's build steps.
2. Click on Add build step.
3. Choose "Command Line" from the dialogue.
4. Configure the build step as follows:
   **Run**: Executable with parameters
   **Command executable**: Enter the path to SpecRun.exe here
   **Command parameters**: Enter the command line parameters for SpecRun.exe here. Use the  BuildServerRun option and include **/buildserver:teamcity**.
   Information on executing command lines in TeamCity is available [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Command-Line). More details on the 
   SpecFlow+ Runner's command line options can be found [here](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlowPlus-Resources/wiki/SpecFlowPlus-Runner-Command-Line).
5. Click on Save.

Taken from https://specflow.org/plus/documentation/SpecFlowPlus-and-TeamCity/

Comment: Hi Andreas, just a heads up that the link to https://specflow.org/plus/documentation/SpecFlowPlus-and-TeamCity/ is no longer valid.